# What is the meaning of Right Hand Limit at $\infty$?

Tags: limits, functions, infinity

For a limit to exist, the left hand limit must equal the right hand limit.
That is, $$\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^-} f(x)$$

However, if $x\to\infty$, then what does the right hand limit mean ?
How can $x\to\infty^+$, if $\infty$ is the biggest possible thing? And does this imply that all limits at $x\to\infty$ exist?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty^-} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x)$.

Comment: If $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty^-} f(x)$ does not exist, then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ for a finite $c$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ are *different concepts* with separate definitions. Their notation is similar as a help to remembering them, but formally they are quite separate. In particular, $\infty$ is not "the biggest possible thing" -- it is not a "thing" at all, just a shape of ink we write *instead of* a thing as an informal reminder that $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ is *somewhat like* $\lim_{x\to c}$.

One-sided limits make sense only in the $\lim_{x\to c}$ case -- there is no directly corresponding concepts for limits at infinity.

It is certainly not the case that "all limits at $x\to\infty$" exist. For example,
$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \sin x $
does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Even if one compactfies $\mathbb{R}$, *i.e.* join $\mathbb{R}$ with $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, then there is no such thing as the biggest number in standard analysis.

If you recall that, in defining one-sided limit one takes a point $c \in \mathbb{R}$ at first, then everything is clear.

Also, the phrase "as $x \to \infty$" simply means "as $x$ grows" or "as $x$ goes beyond every bound", and the phrase "as $x \to +\infty$" means "as $x$ grows" when the "direction" is unclear within context.